# How to remove/reduce space betwen text and checkbox of CheckboxListTile in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

How can I reduce/remove the space between the CheckboxListTile and the Text in the following image?

It seems the following line removes the surrounding space only.

```
CheckboxListTile(
    title: Text('Account number not available'),
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
    controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
)
```

[image]

Comment: did you fixed this problem? still using CheckboxListTile? @Hesam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CheckboxListTile` is using `ListTile` which has the same padding as contentPadding so this is not a problem because you set it to 0.0, but it also has field called visualDensity which you cannot set from `CheckboxListTile`. This visualDensity is inherited from `ThemeData`. So either you will set `VisualDensity.compact` in your theme (you still won't be able to completely remove the space you have highlighted, but it will be smaller, it depends on your current `ThemeData` settings), or make a custom `LabeledCheckbox` widget for full flexibility as i did which is not really hard.

**Edit:**

I am using this custom `LabeledCheckbox` widget, you can control the gap between `CheckBox` and `Text` with field `gap`, also it is wrapped with `GestureDetector` so it register tap on the text too, not just the checkbox itself.

```
class LabeledCheckbox extends StatelessWidget {
  const LabeledCheckbox({
    this.label,
    this.contentPadding,
    this.value,
    this.onTap,
    this.activeColor,
    this.fontSize,
    this.gap = 4.0,
    this.bold = false,
  });

  final String label;
  final EdgeInsets contentPadding;
  final bool value;
  final Function onTap;
  final Color activeColor;
  final double fontSize;
  final double gap;
  final bool bold;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => onTap(!value),
      child: Padding(
        padding: contentPadding ?? const EdgeInsets.all(0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Checkbox(
              value: value,
              activeColor: activeColor,
              visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
              onChanged: (val) => onTap(val),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: gap,
            ), // you can control gap between checkbox and label with this field
            Flexible(
              child: Text(
                label,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: fontSize,
                  fontWeight: bold ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I had `VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,` in my theme, I changed it to `compact` and didn't see much improvement. Do you have any references for the second way you suggested?

Comment: I have edited my answer with reference widget. You can customize it as you want.

Comment: ah, you created a custom widget. I thought there is a way to do a similar thing by extending ListTile. Any way, your way works, too.

Comment: In general, don't extend... compose!  Then you don't have to worry about changes in internal protocol.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this

```
ListTileTheme(
    horizontalTitleGap: 0,
    child: CheckboxListTile(
      controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
      title: Text(
        title,
        style: kRegularFontStyle.copyWith(
          fontSize: 16.0.sp,
          color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1!.color,
        ),
      ),
      value: isChecked,
      onChanged: onChanged,
      activeColor: kStructuralBlue500,
      checkColor: kWhiteColor,
      checkboxShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0.r)),
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Well, this is the correct answer I think. Because with this one, InkWell works.

Answer (score 1):

**Above All Answers Are Showing Complicated Ways**. *It's ACTUALLY SIMPLE*. Don't use `CheckboxListTile`. instead use `CheckBox` with `Text` in `Row` with `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` as shown in *Example Code* and set these properties to `CheckBox`:

```
materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
```

**Check This Example Code**

```
Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: [
    
    Checkbox(
      materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
      visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
      value: true,
      onChanged: (newValue){
        //Do Something When Value Changes to True Or False
        
      },
    ),
    
    Text('Account number not available'),
    
  ]
)
```

**Final Result**

[image: IMAGE SHOWS THE FINAL RESULT AFTER IMPLEMENTING CHECKBOX IN RIGHT WAY]

**Enjoy!!**

Answer (score 0):

I reworked a complete widget inspired by the accepted answer that actually does not work (no state management, null safety, and gesture detector issue).

```
class LabeledCheckbox extends StatefulWidget {

  final String label;
  final EdgeInsets? contentPadding;
  final bool value;
  final Function onTap;
  final Color activeColor;
  final double fontSize;
  final double gap;
  final bool bold;

  const LabeledCheckbox({
    required this.label,
    this.contentPadding,
    required this.value,
    required this.onTap,
    this.activeColor = Colors.blueAccent,
    this.fontSize = 16.0,
    this.gap = 4.0,
    this.bold = false,
  });

  @override
  State<LabeledCheckbox> createState() => _LabeledCheckboxState();
}

class _LabeledCheckboxState extends State<LabeledCheckbox> {

  late bool _checkboxValue;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _checkboxValue = widget.value;
    super.initState();
  }

  void _updateCheckBox(bool val){
    setState(() {
      _checkboxValue = val;
      // call ontap with new value
      widget.onTap(_checkboxValue);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () => _updateCheckBox(!_checkboxValue),
      child: Padding(
        padding: widget.contentPadding ?? const EdgeInsets.all(0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Checkbox(
                value: _checkboxValue,
                activeColor: widget.activeColor,
                visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
                onChanged: (val){
                  _updateCheckBox(val??false);
                }
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: widget.gap,
            ), // you can control gap between checkbox and label with this field
            Flexible(
              child: Text(
                widget.label,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: widget.fontSize,
                  fontWeight: widget.bold ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can find a full [working exemple on dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=8b2c6a68a62bb20f74c4fc5ea3826565)